# How to create a GrammaticalRelation in Stanford CoreNLP

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I have recently upgraded to the latest version of Stanford CoreNLP.  The code I previously used to get the subject or object in a sentence was

```
System.out.println("subject: "+dependencies.getChildWithReln(dependencies.getFirstRoot(), EnglishGrammaticalRelations.NOMINAL_SUBJECT));
```

but this now returns `null`.

I have tried creating a relation with

```
GrammaticalRelation subjreln =
                edu.stanford.nlp.trees.GrammaticalRelation.valueOf("nsubj");
```

without success.  If I extract a relation using code like

```
GrammaticalRelation target = (dependencies.childRelns(dependencies.getFirstRoot())).iterator().next();
```

Then run the same request,

```
System.out.println("target: "+dependencies.getChildWithReln(dependencies.getFirstRoot(), target));
```

then I get the desired result, confirming that the parsing worked fine (I also know this from printing out the full dependencies).

I suspect my problem has to do with the switch to universal dependencies, but I don't know how to create the GrammaticalRelation from scratch in a way that will match what the dependency parser found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since version 3.5.2 the default dependency representation in CoreNLP is [Universal Dependencies](http://universaldependencies.github.io/docs/). This new representation is implemented in a different class (`UniversalEnglishGrammaticalRelations`) so the `GrammaticalStructure` objects are now defined somewhere else.

All you have to do to use the new version is to replace `EnglishGrammaticalRelations` with `UniversalGrammaticalRelations`:

```
System.out.println("subject: "+dependencies.getChildWithReln(dependencies.getFirstRoot(), UniversalEnglishGrammaticalRelations.NOMINAL_SUBJECT));
```

Note, however, that some relations in the new representation are different and might no longer exist (`nsubj` still does). We are currently compiling [migration guidelines](http://universaldependencies.github.io/docs/en/overview/migration-guidelines.html) from the old representation to the new Universal Dependencies relations. It is still incomplete but it already contains all relation names and their class names in CoreNLP.

Comment: Thanks. Part of the confusion came from the fact that the relations appeared to be the same (same name / short name) but the `equals` method actually also checks the language field is the same.  This had changed from English to Universal English.